# Send a command to another server with ssh

Tags: ssh

So basicly I need to send a command from one server to another.

```
ssh root@address.com 'My command'
```

How do I specify the password?

Answer (score 2):

If have two options:

- just use the command line you already typed, you will be asked for the password of user "root"
- setup password-less authentication, like this: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-9c5717fe7f9bb26332c9d67571200f8c1e4324bc , your command will be executed using the SSH key and you won't be asked to insert the password

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing it in php, so how can I make it type the password after?

Comment: Well, in this case you can use @Samuel sshpass tool, but I strongly reccomend using SSH key authentication instead of writing your password in a PHP file, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) utility.

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then send commands via:

```
sshpass -p '<password>' <ssh/scp command>
```